# Does song DLC for Drum 'n' Fun! also work in Rhythm Festival?

Tags: taiko-no-tatsujin

This question pertains to two **Taiko no Tatsujin** titles for Nintendo Switch:

- [Taiko no Tatsujin: Drum 'n' Fun!](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/taiko-no-tatsujin-drum-n-fun-switch/)
- [Taiko no Tatsujin: Rhythm Festival](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/taiko-no-tatsujin-rhythm-festival-switch/)

If I own Drum 'n' Fun! and have purchased song DLC for it, will that DLC also work (will the songs be playable) in Rhythm Festival?

I am hoping all the Taiko titles can share [the music library](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/taiko-no-tatsujin-drum-n-fun-switch/dlc/) that is offered via DLC, as it is pretty extensive (currently 304 songs, I believe), and not cheap to collect. If the songs cannot be shared between games, it seems like a waste to buy any new Taiko games. Unfortunately, from what I can find, there seems to be no indication of cross-compatibility.

Comment: I don't own those two games, but I don't think they would share the songs (since DLC doesn't work like that; they can only be activated/used in specific game, in this case drum 'n' fun or rhythm festival). Never heard of any game shares their DLC, except when it's got remastered or something. Anyway, that's how Bandai Namco sells their games... Idol M@ster for example, in their newest title there's 137 of DLCs and total of it's cost is almost 1000 USD, and they don't share the DLC in any way.

Comment: @Skye-AT I suspect you are correct. It's too bad really, because if the DLC did carry over it would motivate me to buy future games of the franchise. Owning a game makes me interested in the DLC. But it could go the other way too, if I'm already invested in previous DLC, I would be more likely to buy future titles if I knew I could use my collection of songs (or whatever the DLC is) in those titles too.

Comment: @Skye-AT Although it's not DLC, one example I can think of that supports the transfer of collectibles between games is [Pokémon GO to Pokémon Let's Go!](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001445363-How-do-I-link-games-and-transfer-Pok%C3%A9mon-from-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-to-Pok%C3%A9mon-Let-s-Go-Pikachu-and-Pok%C3%A9mon-Let-s-Go-Eevee-) So the concept is not completely unheard of. The more time or money has been invested in acquiring collectibles in a game, the more relevant the issue becomes.

Comment: One reason that I can think of is that if the DLC's got any songs that has copy righted songs, they'd need to renew their rights to use the songs in their games, so they're trying to recover the licensing fee by making DLCs purchasable. Plus, even if Bamco has the copy right, they'd still need to pay the license fee to the creator of the song. Personally, I don't mind if I have to rebuy the song DLCs in their new title, since I don't buy all of the DLCs, just the pack that has interesting / favorite songs... :p That shouldn't cost too much, right?

Comment: As for the "example"... Personally, I don't count that as same case as this one. Collectibles doesn't involve real money to collect, just needs the player's effort and time. If you're going to count that one, you'd probably need to count the Pokémon transferring between old / new series of Pokémon. They aren't essentially same, although the concept seems to be similar. Paying money to obtain DLCs isn't as same as transferring collectibles and Pokémons, at least in my book (though I feel not everyone think as same as me so I don't deny having different ideas).

Comment: As a point of comparison, [Taiko no Tatsujin: Rhythmic Adventure Pack](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/taiko-no-tatsujin-rhythmic-adventure-pack-switch/) doesn't have any DLC, but its song list includes a few songs that are DLC in Drum 'n' Fun (but it's not a perfect overlap).

Comment: @ConMan Oh, that's an interesting observation. And yes, since Rhythmic has no DLC, maybe I shouldn't compare the two to begin with. It would seem that what Rhythmic is, is something different than what I hoped it would be. So it's probably not for me, and I guess there's no point in wondering about it further.

Comment: The Taiko RPGs are definitely slightly odd beasts. If you just want to play songs, then I'd recomment you stick with Drum'n'Fun, even though I did enjoy Rhythmic Adventure Pack for what it is.